# How to fix the SQL error "Error converting data type varchar to numeric"?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am selecting records from a SQL Server database but result says that the query completed with errors and then error I get is

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric

In my query I am fetching records based on particular codes and then I use the `=` the query fails but using `<>` the query runs. Can anyone assist me where I am doing it wrong because I looked for solutions provided they are not working for me.

I am sharing by query below

```sql
SELECT
    MAX(amount) AS amount, 
    MAX(date_of_payment) AS date_of_payment, 
    MAX(customer) AS customer, 
    MAX(payment_type) AS payment_type, 
    MAX(currency) AS currency, 
    MAX(PayCtrNum) AS PayCtrNum, 
    MAX(TRACKING_NO) AS TRACKING_NO, 
    MAX(Payment_id) AS Payment_id 
FROM 
    PAYMENTS_VW 
WHERE 
    date_of_payment = '21/01/2020' 
    AND account_code = '440342' 
GROUP BY 
    Payment_id
```

Comment: And the types of the involved columns are?..

Comment: probably `customer`

Comment: Amount=Float,date_of_payment=VARCHAR,customer=VARCHAR,currency=VARCHAR,PayCtrNum=varchar

Comment: Only `date_of_payment` and `account_code` are involved, and you haven't mentioned the latter. It is very wrong of course that you store your dates as strings, but it would not cause *this* error.

Comment: account_code is varchar.And when i put <> instead of = at account_code condition it works.Only for = is not working

Comment: date_of_payment can not be integer as you are matching with '21/10/2020' which contains '/' symbol.

Comment: You said [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59907201/how-to-fix-the-an-sql-error-error-converting-data-type-varchar-to-numeric#comment105940628_59907201) that `date_of_payment` is `varchar`. If it is an number (which is even more wrong for storing a date), then what kind of *number* is `21/01/2020` supposed to be?

Comment: And if it is integer then you can not match with '21/01/2020' value.

Comment: I was wrong,in my mind i meant account_code which is again varchar....I have used AND CAST(account_code AS int) = '440342' i see it working

Answer (score 0):

I have used CAST and changed the column to Int it is working now. The query now reads

```
SELECT max(amount) as amount, 
max(date_of_payment) as date_of_payment, 
max(customer) as customer, 
max(payment_type) as payment_type, 
max(currency) as currency, 
max(PayCtrNum) as PayCtrNum, 
max(TRACKING_NO) as TRACKING_NO, 
max(Payment_id) as Payment_id 
FROM PAYMENTS_VW 
WHERE date_of_payment = '21/01/2020' 
AND CAST(account_code AS int) = '440342' 
GROUP BY Payment_id
```

And it is working

Comment: The you so much,you gave me the highlights when you asked about datatypes

Comment: Surely that cannot be your solution. If `account_code` is `varchar` like you are [saying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59907201/how-to-fix-the-an-sql-error-error-converting-data-type-varchar-to-numeric#comment105940735_59907201), then it's *wrong* to cast it to `int` before comparing it to *another `varchar`* which `'440342'` is. I'm pretty sure at this point that this is not the actual query you are running and/or that you need to show the full `create table` statement for your table.

Comment: @Gserg . . . I could only imagine this causing the code to work by changing the execution plan.  The `FROM` clause is referencing a view and who knows what is happening there.  The OP should not depend on this fix actually working.